# How to pass an array to calendar's markedDates

Tags: react-native

Today i am working on Calendar control and used [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendars-wybztl)

Library please check it.

So now my question is about how do i pass an array of dates in markedDates

i have used this ::

```
//Here is My State
    state={
        markedData:['2017-11-12','2017-11-16'],
      }

// Here is what i have do in Calendar control view
    markedDates= {{[this.state.markedData]: {selected: true}}}
```

but there is nothing happen, so can you please help me to sort out from this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the array markedData to object, like below

```
let dates = {};
this.state.markedData.forEach((val) => {
  dates[val] = {selected: true};
});
```

Now, while passing value to **markedDates** prop, pass the newly constructed object like

```
markedDates= {dates}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: getting an error like forEach and i tried to solve out but there is another errors are occured so this can't help but thanks for response

Comment: I did executed the code before posting here, its gave me result as expected. Can u please share what error you are getting with 'forEach'

Comment: yehh thanks a lot i have successfully execute this line of codes

Answer (score 0):

```
markedDates= {{
[this.state.markedData]: {selected: true, marked: true},
}}
```

You have missed to state the marked as **true**, if not this prob, then first you can check whether the **[this.state.markedData]** contains the date or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar solution, because I been trying the ones you posted, but for my version of React it wasn't working.

```js
const datesList = [2023-04-04], [2023-05-24, [2023-09-30]


//Push the array of dates to convert it into an object

let dates = {}

 datesList.forEach( 
    (item )=> {dates[item] = {selected: true}}
 )
```

Then, inside my component function:

```js
<View>
      <CalendarList
          markedDates={dates}
      />
</View>
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**